# Adding manual p-values to grouped bargraph in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

I am trying to add a manual p-value to my grouped bargraph on ggplot2. I have tried the geom_sigf function suggested in previous posts (with manual coordinates) but there is no output on my graph. I would like to add "<0.001" for the three comparisons across the graph.

```
data <- data.frame(group = c("A", "B","A", "B","A", "B"),
               variable = c("X", "X", "Y", "Y", "Z", "Z"),
               value = c(10, 40, 1, 15, 10, 25))

ggplot(data = data, aes(fill=group, x=variable, y=value)) +
 geom_bar(position="dodge", stat = "identity") +
 geom_text(aes(label=value), position=position_dodge(width=0.9), vjust=-0.2, size = 5) +
 labs(x = "") +
 labs(y="Proportion (%)") +
 theme(legend.title = element_blank(), legend.position = "bottom") +
 theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size=12, color = "black")) +
 theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12)) +
 theme(legend.text = element_text(size = 12)) +
 theme(axis.title.y = element_text(size = 12)) +
 scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,60))
```

[image]`

Much appreciated!

Comment: You can insert text onto a plot with `annotate`, but ideally you would calculate your pvalues and designate significance on the plot in one 'step'. This tutorial outlines how this can be done: https://www.datanovia.com/en/lessons/anova-in-r/ , and the ggpubr vignette is also useful: http://rpkgs.datanovia.com/ggpubr/reference/stat_pvalue_manual.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use annotate:

```
data <- data.frame(group = c("A", "B","A", "B","A", "B"),
                   variable = c("X", "X", "Y", "Y", "Z", "Z"),
                   value = c(10, 40, 1, 15, 10, 25))

ggplot(data = data, aes(fill=group, x=variable, y=value)) +
  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(aes(label=value), position=position_dodge(width=0.9), vjust=-0.2, size = 5) +
  labs(x = "") +
  labs(y="Proportion (%)") +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank(), legend.position = "bottom") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size=12, color = "black")) +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12)) +
  theme(legend.text = element_text(size = 12)) +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(size = 12)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,60))  +
  annotate(geom="text", x=3, y=50, label="<0.001",
           color="black") +
  annotate(geom="text", x=2, y=50, label="<0.001",
           color="black") + 
  annotate(geom="text", x=1, y=50, label="<0.001",
           color="black")
```

Comment: Thank you for the input. Is there a way to still incorporate a bracket beneath the p-value using the geom_text or annotate methods?

Comment: Yes, you can use annotate. Not the most elegant way, but here is an example that will put a line under the text in the middle `annotate("segment", x = 1.9, xend = 2.1, y = 48, yend = 48)`

Comment: Sorry, you asked for brackets, not lines. Take a look at the package [ggBrackets](https://github.com/azzoam/ggBrackets)

Answer (score 1):

I usually solve this problem by adding a `geom_text` layer with my p-values and labels from a different data frame. You have to move the fill aesthetic to the geoms that use it since it is not present in the `annot` data frame. The advantage of this is you can develop pipelines to calculate p-values and insert them programmatically. By setting `ypos` to `Inf` with vjust, the text should always be near the top of the graph. This should work:

```
annot <- 
  tibble(
    variable = c("X", "Y", "Z"), 
    label = rep("< 0.001", 3), 
    ypos = Inf, 
    vjustvar = 2
  )

ggplot(data = data, aes(x=variable, y=value)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = group), position="dodge", stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(aes(fill = group, label=value), position=position_dodge(width=0.9), vjust=-0.2, size = 5) +
  geom_text(
    data = annot, 
    aes(label = label, y = ypos, vjust = vjustvar)
  ) +
  labs(x = "") +
  labs(y="Proportion (%)") +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank(), legend.position = "bottom") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size=12, color = "black")) +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12)) +
  theme(legend.text = element_text(size = 12)) +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(size = 12)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,60))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data <- data.frame(group = c("A", "B","A", "B","A", "B"),
variable = c("X", "X", "Y", "Y", "Z", "Z"),
value = c(10, 40, 1, 15, 10, 25))

ggplot(data = data, aes(fill=group, x=variable, y=value)) +
geom_bar(position="dodge", stat = "identity") +
geom_text(aes(label=value), 
position=position_dodge(width=0.9), vjust=-0.2, size = 5) +
labs(x = "") +
labs(y="Proportion (%)") +
theme(legend.title = element_blank(), legend.position = 
"bottom") +
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size=12, color = 
"black")) +
theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12)) +
theme(legend.text = element_text(size = 12)) +
theme(axis.title.y = element_text(size = 12)) +
scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,60)) +
annotate("rect", xmin = 0.75, xmax = 1.25, ymin = 50, ymax 
=50, alpha = 1, color = "black") +
annotate("rect", xmin = 0.75, xmax = 0.75, ymin = 49, ymax 
=50.09, alpha=1, colour = "black") +
annotate("rect", xmin = 1.25, xmax = 1.25, ymin = 49, ymax 
=50.09, alpha=1, colour = "black")+       
annotate("rect", xmin = 1.75, xmax = 2.25, ymin = 25, ymax 
=25, alpha = 1, color = "black") +
annotate("rect", xmin = 1.75, xmax = 1.75, ymin = 24, ymax 
=25.09, alpha=1, colour = "black") +
annotate("rect", xmin = 2.25, xmax = 2.25, ymin = 24, ymax 
=25.09, alpha=1, colour = "black") +
annotate("rect", xmin = 2.75, xmax = 3.25, ymin = 36, ymax 
=36, alpha = 1, color = "black") +
annotate("rect", xmin = 2.75, xmax = 2.75, ymin = 35, ymax 
=36.09, alpha=1, colour = "black") +
annotate("rect", xmin = 3.25, xmax = 3.25, ymin = 35, ymax 
=36.09, alpha=1, colour = "black") +
annotate(geom = "text", x = 1.0, y = 52, label = "p 
<0.01", 
color = "black") +
annotate(geom = "text", x = 2.0, y = 27, label = "p 
<0.01", 
color = "black") +
annotate(geom = "text", x = 3.0, y = 38, label = "p 
<0.01", 
color = "black")
```

Not elegant at all but was able to annotate horizontal and vertical lines to create the brackets and add p-values. Will have to try out ggbracket next time.